# Can I monkey patch a module to use a different implementation of another package?

Tags: python, json, monkeypatching

I'm using a third-party module that makes heavy use of the `json` library. Is there a way to monkey patch the whole module to use a higher-performance package like `ujson`?

Comment: you can certainly manually rewrite the source code

Comment: I guess it depends on how the 3'rd part module is implemented